# Batch split a text file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, text, cmd

I have this batch file to split a txt file:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "PASSWORD.txt"') do for /f "delims=~" %%c in ("%%~b") do >"text%%a.txt" echo(%%c
pause
```

It works but it splits it line by line. How do i make it split it every 5000 lines. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
I have just tried this:

@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
REM Edit this value to change the name of the file that needs splitting. Include the extension.
SET BFN=passwordAll.txt
REM Edit this value to change the number of lines per file.
SET LPF=50000
REM Edit this value to change the name of each short file. It will be followed by a number indicating where it is in the list.
SET SFN=SplitFile

REM Do not change beyond this line.

SET SFX=%BFN:~-3%

SET /A LineNum=0
SET /A FileNum=1

For /F "delims==" %%l in (%BFN%) Do (
SET /A LineNum+=1

echo %%l >> %SFN%!FileNum!.%SFX%

if !LineNum! EQU !LPF! (
SET /A LineNum=0
SET /A FileNum+=1
)

)
endlocal
Pause
exit
```

But i get an error saying: `Not enough storage is available to process this command`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you the a basic skeleton. Adapt as needed

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "nLines=5000"
    set "line=0"

    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("passwords.txt") do (
        set /a "file=line/%nLines%", "line+=1"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for %%b in (!file!) do (
            endlocal
            >>"passwords_%%b.txt" echo(%%a
        )
    )

    endlocal
```

**EDITED**

As the comments indicated, a 4.3GB file is hard to manage. `for /f` needs to load the full file into memory, and the buffer needed is twice this size as the file is converted to unicode in memory.

This is a fully ad hoc solution. I've not tested it over a file that high, but at least in theory it should work (unless 5000 lines needs a lot of memory, it depends of the line length)

AND, with such a file it will be SLOW

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "line=0"
    set "tempFile=%temp%\passwords.tmp"

    findstr /n "^" passwords.txt > "%tempFile%"
    for /f %%a in ('type passwords.txt ^| find /c /v "" ') do set /a "nFiles=%%a/5000"

    for /l %%a in (0 1 %nFiles%) do (
        set /a "e1=%%a*5", "e2=e1+1", "e3=e2+1", "e4=e3+1", "e5=e4+1"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        if %%a equ 0 (
            set "e=/c:"[1-9]:" /c:"[1-9][0-9]:" /c:"[1-9][0-9][0-9]:" /c:"!e2![0-9][0-9][0-9]:" /c:"!e3![0-9][0-9][0-9]:" /c:"!e4![0-9][0-9][0-9]:" /c:"!e5![0-9][0-9][0-9]:" "
        ) else (
            set "e=/c:"!e1![0-9][0-9][0-9]:" /c:"!e2![0-9][0-9][0-9]:" /c:"!e3![0-9][0-9][0-9]:" /c:"!e4![0-9][0-9][0-9]:" /c:"!e5![0-9][0-9][0-9]:" "
        )
        for /f "delims=" %%e in ("!e!") do (
            endlocal & (for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%b in ('findstr /r /b %%e "%tempFile%"') do @echo(%%c)>passwords_%%a.txt
        )
    )

    del "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul

    endlocal
```

**EDITED**, again: Previous code will not correctly work for lines starting with a colon, as it has been used as a delimiter in the `for` command to separate line numbers from data.

For an alternative, still pure batch but still SLOW

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "nLines=5000"
    set "line=0"
    for /f %%a in ('type passwords.txt^|find /c /v ""') do set "fileLines=%%a"

    < "passwords.txt" (for /l %%a in (1 1 %fileLines%) do (
        set /p "data="
        set /a "file=line/%nLines%", "line+=1"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"passwords_!file!.txt" echo(!data!
        endlocal
    ))

    endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks i have just tried it and it says: `Not enough storage is available to process this command`

Comment: How large is your file?  Multiple GB?

Comment: The `for` command can't parse a file that large.  I don't have a reference but it may also be a limit in memory, I'm not certain. On my 32 bit system in the past I found a file around 3 GB would fail.  A plain for script would be very slow on a file near that size too.

Comment: @09stephenb, code updated, try it if you have patience enough ;)

Answer (score 3):

Test this: the input file is `"file.txt"` and output files are `"splitfile-5000.txt"` for example.

This uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or on the path.

```
@echo off
:: splits file.txt into 5000 line chunks. 
set chunks=5000

set /a s=1-chunks
:loop
set /a s=s+chunks
set /a e=s+chunks-1
echo %s% to %e%
call findrepl /o:%s%:%e% <"file.txt" >"splitfile-%e%.txt"
for %%b in ("splitfile-%e%.txt") do (if %%~zb EQU 0 del "splitfile-%e%.txt" & goto :done)
goto :loop
:done
pause
```

A limitation is the number of lines in the file and the real largest number is `2^31 - 1` where batch math tops out.

Comment: Thanks but i seem to be getting this error: `CScript Error: Can't find script engine "JScript" for script "C:\Users\09stephenb\Desktop\batch\findrepl.bat".`

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?  Is it locked down by IT perhaps?

Comment: I changed the code because of a long delay and zero byte files - but your jscript issue might be because your Windows is locked down in your company.

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

findstr /N "^" PASSWORD.txt > temp.txt
set part=0
call :splitFile < temp.txt
del temp.txt
goto :EOF

:splitFile
set /A part+=1
(for /L %%i in (1,1,5000) do (
   set "line="
   set /P line=
   if defined line echo(!line:*:=!
)) >  text%part%.txt
if defined line goto splitFile
exit /B
```

If the input file has not empty lines, previous method may be modified in order to run faster.