# How to split large text file in windows?

Tags: windows, text, cmd, split, size

I have a log file with size of 2.5 GB. Is there any way to split this file into smaller files using windows command prompt?

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23593556/2152082)

Comment: https://github.com/Mitch-Wheat/FileSplitter

Answer (score 391, accepted):

If you have installed [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download), you should have Git Bash installed, since that comes with Git.

Use the **`split`** command in Git Bash to split a file:

- into files of size 500MB each: **`split myLargeFile.txt -b 500m`**
- into files with 10000 lines each: **`split myLargeFile.txt -l 10000`**

**Tips:**

- If you don't have Git/Git Bash, download at https://git-scm.com/download
- If you lost the shortcut to Git Bash, you can run it using **`C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe`**

## That's it!

---

I always like examples though...

**Example:**

[image]

You can see in this image that the files generated by **`split`** are named `xaa`, `xab`, `xac`, etc.

These names are made up of a prefix and a suffix, which you can specify. Since I didn't specify what I want the prefix or suffix to look like, the prefix defaulted to `x`, and the suffix defaulted to a two-character alphabetical enumeration.

**Another Example:**

This example demonstrates

- using a filename prefix of `MySlice` (instead of the default `x`),
- the `-d` flag for using numerical suffixes (instead of `aa`, `ab`, `ac`, etc...),
- and the option `-a 5` to tell it I want the suffixes to be 5 digits long:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution with good example. Works well for me in Windows 10. For me I used `split myLogs.log mylogs_ -b 800m -a 3 -d` to split a 4.5Gb log file.

Comment: Nice solution by using Git-bash on Windows. For the `split` part, using _filename prefix_ and `-d` options should be on your main answer. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45761990/1519522

Comment: Thanks for this, worked great!! Working with Windows 10 and being new to Git bash this might be helpful... the default directory to work in was C:\Users\username (find your current working directory with "dir"). The command to change directory is "cd /c/folder".

Comment: ok, but if I want to select *.txt in Git Bash, why is not working? such as: `split *.txt MyNewText  -b 5m`

Comment: Nice! You can also set the extension on the outputs ... e.g. --additional-suffix=.txt

Comment: Now that you can easily get full Linux subsystems inside of Windows 10, you don't need Git for Windows or anything like that - just fire up an Ubuntu terminal and run from there. Really handy for stuff like this.

Comment: Can also install `Git Bash` via [Chocolatey's `git`](https://chocolatey.org/packages/git)... `choco install git`

Comment: Mannn.. this is exactly what I was looking for. I wish MS could include this with Windows by default so that I may think about loving Windows again :)

Comment: Great, It worked for me, but I have to convert the extension to .sql. I would like to share the command for knowledge. 
split mylargefile.sql -l 10231 --additional-suffix=.sql

it will generate files after each 10231 lines and with suffix .sql

Comment: If you don't have git bash installed: https://github.com/Mitch-Wheat/FileSplitter

Comment: I am suprised for a quickly splitting 2GB+ text file to 500mb ones in some miliseconds !  Thanks.

Comment: then how to put them together into one file?

Comment: @AlbertChen use `split myLargeFile.txt slice_ -l 1000` then `cat slice_* > combined.txt`

Comment: @JoshWithee is there a guarantee that the order keeps the same?

Comment: @Nij, Thanks! The question needs to be edited to add your comment!

Comment: Longest settup wizard EVER!

Answer (score 5):

You must have **Git Bash** installed, and work inside that terminal/shell.

You can use the command **split** for this task.
For example, this command entered into the command prompt

```
split YourLogFile.txt -b 500m
```

creates several files with a size of 500 MByte each. This will take several minutes for a file of your size. You can rename the output files (by default called "xaa", "xab",... and so on) to *.txt to open it in the editor of your choice.

Make sure to check the help file for the command. You can also split the log file by the number of lines or change the name of your output files.

tested on

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: "'split' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." - on Win 7 Ultimate SP1, 64 bit

Comment: I believe you actually used gitbash's split

Comment: ok, but if I want to select *.txt in Git Bash, why is not working? such as: split *.txt MyNewText -b 5m

Comment: I tried on Windows 10 with GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release and it worked as advertised

Comment: It works just fine from "Git Bash" Terminal inside PyCharm IDE, Windows 10 host. Thanks!

Comment: -b 500m gives me tons of small files (500 bytes I think) on windows. I used -n 4

Answer (score 3):

Below code split file every 500

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
REM Edit this value to change the name of the file that needs splitting. Include the extension.
SET BFN=upload.txt
REM Edit this value to change the number of lines per file.
SET LPF=15000
REM Edit this value to change the name of each short file. It will be followed by a number indicating where it is in the list.
SET SFN=SplitFile

REM Do not change beyond this line.

SET SFX=%BFN:~-3%

SET /A LineNum=0
SET /A FileNum=1

For /F "delims==" %%l in (%BFN%) Do (
SET /A LineNum+=1

echo %%l >> %SFN%!FileNum!.%SFX%

if !LineNum! EQU !LPF! (
SET /A LineNum=0
SET /A FileNum+=1
)

)
endlocal
Pause
```

See below:
https://forums.techguy.org/threads/solved-split-a-100000-line-csv-into-5000-line-csv-files-with-dos-batch.1023949/

Answer (score 2):

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "LineNumber", 4 

        .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
        .Open
        LineCount = 0
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            LineCount = LineCount + 1
            .AddNew
            .Fields("LineNumber").value = LineCount
            .Fields("Txt").value = Inp.readline
            .UpDate
        Loop

        .Sort = "LineNumber ASC"

        If LCase(Arg(1)) = "t" then
            If LCase(Arg(2)) = "i" then
                .filter = "LineNumber < " & LCase(Arg(3)) + 1
            ElseIf LCase(Arg(2)) = "x" then
                .filter = "LineNumber > " & LCase(Arg(3))
            End If
        ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "b" then
            If LCase(Arg(2)) = "i" then
                .filter = "LineNumber > " & LineCount - LCase(Arg(3))
            ElseIf LCase(Arg(2)) = "x" then
                .filter = "LineNumber < " & LineCount - LCase(Arg(3)) + 1
            End If
        End If

        Do While not .EOF
            Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value

            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
```

**Cut**

```
filter cut {t|b} {i|x} NumOfLines
```

Cuts the number of lines from the top or bottom of file.

```
t - top of the file
b - bottom of the file
i - include n lines
x - exclude n lines
```

**Example**

```
cscript /nologo filter.vbs cut t i 5 < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

Another way This outputs lines 5001+, adapt for your use. This uses almost no memory.

```
Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
         Count = Count + 1
         If count > 5000 then
            OutP.WriteLine Inp.Readline
         End If
Loop
```

Comment: when i try to run the script i got error like filter.vbs(16, 13) Microsoft Cursor Engine: Out of memory.

Comment: Do you have 32 or 64 bit windows. If 64 bit run it from the 64 bit version (`c:\windows\sysnative\cscript etc` - sysnative forces System32 files to be run rather than SysWoW64 files for32 bit processes). If 32 bit we need another technique, which will be specific rather than generic.

Comment: I have a 64 bit windows.

Comment: So I told you what to do in that case. Sysnative forces 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is! Win CMD can do a lot more than just split text files :)

Split a text file into separate files of 'max' lines each:

```
Split text file (max lines each):
: Initialize
set input=file.txt
set max=10000

set /a line=1 >nul
set /a file=1 >nul
set out=!file!_%input%
set /a max+=1 >nul

echo Number of lines in %input%:
find /c /v "" < %input%

: Split file
for /f "tokens=* delims=[" %i in ('type "%input%" ^| find /v /n ""') do (

if !line!==%max% (
set /a line=1 >nul
set /a file+=1 >nul
set out=!file!_%input%
echo Writing file: !out!
)

REM Write next file
set a=%i
set a=!a:*]=]!
echo:!a:~1!>>out!
set /a line+=1 >nul
)
```

If above code hangs or crashes, this example code splits files faster (by writing data to intermediate files instead of keeping everything in memory):

eg. To split a file with 7,600 lines into smaller files of maximum 3000 lines.

1. Generate regexp string/pattern files with `set` command to be fed to `/g` flag of `findstr`

list1.txt

> \[[0-9]\]
>   \[[0-9][0-9]\]
>   \[[0-9][0-9][0-9]\]
>   \[[0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]\]

list2.txt

> \[[3-5][0-9][0-9][0-9]\]

list3.txt

> \[[6-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\]

2. Split the file into smaller files:

> ```
> type "%input%" | find /v /n "" | findstr /b /r /g:list1.txt > file1.txt
> type "%input%" | find /v /n "" | findstr /b /r /g:list2.txt > file2.txt
> type "%input%" | find /v /n "" | findstr /b /r /g:list3.txt > file3.txt
> ```

3. remove prefixed line numbers **for each** file split:
   eg. for the 1st file:

> ```
> for /f "tokens=* delims=[" %i in ('type "%cd%\file1.txt"') do (
> set a=%i
> set a=!a:*]=]!
> echo:!a:~1!>>file_1.txt)
> ```

**Notes:**

Works with leading whitespace, blank lines & whitespace lines.

Tested on Win 10 x64 CMD, on 4.4GB text file, 5651982 lines.

Comment: how and where can I use this code?

Comment: The test was done on Win 10 x64 command line, on a 4.4GB text file